# Ignore results that generate an error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make the following request

```
SELECT login, time FROM table 
  WHERE time::timestamp <= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '5' month);
```

where time is a text field containing timestamps.

Is there a way I can ignore ignore the rows that generate a cast error when time is not well formatted ?

I've tried the following

```
SELECT login, time FROM table 
  WHERE (((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '6' month)::text || time)::timestamp
    <= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '5' month);
```

But first, this in not beautiful and second, it results in a `ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range` error, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write own cast function in plpgsql with error handling.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_timestamp_ignore_errors(text)
RETURNS timestamp AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN $1::timestamp;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

postgres=# select to_timestamp_ignore_errors('bbbb');
 to_timestamp_ignore_errors 
----------------------------

(1 row)

postgres=# select to_timestamp_ignore_errors('2013-08-16');
 to_timestamp_ignore_errors 
----------------------------
 2013-08-16 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Other possibility is format check before casting - some initial version

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_timestamp_ignore_errors(text)
RETURNS timestamp AS $$
-- regular should be richer 
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$' THEN $1::timestamp ELSE NULL END;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;       
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# select to_timestamp_ignore_errors('2013-08-16');
 to_timestamp_ignore_errors 
----------------------------
 2013-08-16 00:00:00
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_timestamp_ignore_errors('bbbb');
 to_timestamp_ignore_errors 
----------------------------

(1 row)
```

Tested on 9.2

Regular expression based version should be little bit faster (30%) when there are a minimum errors, and really faster when is lot of errors, so this solution is preferable. So, preferable solution is cleaning a data and using good types.

Comment: Thank you. I hopped to find a *more generic* solution, but I'll work with function if there is no other way. Something like a configuration  or something that would have make the condition return *false* in case of an error would have been great.

Comment: @TomAhh PostgreSQL is not designed for uncleaned data, sorry. There are no any generic solution. Your data are badly designed, and you are searching workaround. Other possibility is hacking postgres - source code is available and this kind of modification don't need more then 1day work. But this modification will be accepted in upstream newer - because it is really ugly (but sometimes some men have to do ugly things :))

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a more fundamental problem here. The time not well formatted? I'm assuming, from the context of the SQL, that we're recording the time that someone logged in to some system. Whoever is generating that time (it could be the database, or maybe you're assembling the time manually) needs to do it properly. Getting the time, and saving it, is something we should be able to do reliably.

There's no sense in writing code to work around junk data. Make sure the data is valid.

Comment: I'm working with a system on which I don't have the power to make those changes. But I agree with you, in an ideal world, the time column should be a timestamp.